# What do you call the empty/arid zones on both sides of a highway?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm referring to something like the brown areas in this picture:

[image]

Comment: do you mean the road *shoulders*?

Comment: What does *this* stand for in "something like this"?

Comment: Indeed, I thought the answer was "Arizona".  You need to **include an arrow** in photos like that.  Every single computer operating system now has a thing where you can add an arrow to a picture. On your Mac just click "Annotate".

Comment: @Joe Blow How about now?

Comment: @JoeBlow This is StackExchange, you should use [freehand circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/205964), not arrows.

Comment: Beyond the so called shoulder there is a depression or roadside ditch that may be called a barrow pit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The edge of the road (as others have mentioned) is the *shoulder*.

Beyond the shoulder is the *verge*.

The whole strip of land the road follows is called a right-of-way in some places and a *reserve* in other places.

Comment: You know, it's often called the "hard shoulder".  It's one of those cases where you can have a hard shoulder or a soft shoulder, but, for no real reason people to some extent slightly prefer to say "hard shoulder" when just referring to the shoulder (with no particular concern whether it is hard or soft).

Comment: Yes, that's when it's paved, and so vehicles can safely stop from speed, or stop without sinking to their axles :-)

Comment: Hey Andy -- you know (A) I'm not certain that "hard shoulder" always means PAVED, TARMAC in all English-speaking area.  For example in Australia, a "hard shoulder" means the shoulder is dirt, but, it is correctly formed, perhaps gravel (like a gravel road, you know?) whereas a soft shoulder means the shoulder is rubbish, ie it is just sand or untamed, as it were, natural earth (as opposed to "well-made, compressed, perhaps gravel").  So it's an interesting one.  Note too that "hard shoulder" is (I think) never at all used for the actual "fully correctly made" emergency lane on a freeway.

Comment: No, I didn't know you weren't certain :-) But I do agree with you, it's not always paved. P'raps I should have said that's usually when it's paved ... .

Comment: Yes I believe there may be regional variation in that usage, in different English-language areas...

Comment: _Shoulder_ always reminds me of a joke I first heard on the old _Bert & I_ records. Exasperated driver, frustrated with the confusing directions he's being given: "You know there's not much between you and a fool..." Local: "Just the shoulder of the road."

Comment: In the US, the distinction is between "paved" and "unpaved" shoulder, but unless there's a warning sign about "soft shoulder", it is assumed that either variant is firm enough to support a vehicle of ordinary weight.

Comment: @J.R. A very quick local. I'd give him the cold ~ :-)

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question largely depends upon the context.

If you mean the land on which the highway passes through, this is known as a [**right of way**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-of-way_%28transportation%29).  Essentially, it is land granted for passage of highways and railways. And, typically the zone of the right of way extends quite a bit on either side of the roadway.

If you are referring to the waste area (undeveloped/uninhabited land) on either side when driving through a desert, you usually will refer to this by the specific biome or flora you see.  For example: [*salt flats*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonneville_Salt_Flats), *desert*, *cactus patch*, *red rock mesas*, etc.

If you mean the strip of land immediately adjacent to a road, often covered in gravel, this is known as the [**shoulder of the road**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoulder_%28road%29).  This area is typically used for stopping at roadside, or for the passage of emergency vehicles.

Comment: In some places I think it's also called *berm.*

Comment: @BraddSzonye I've heard that term, too.

Comment: andy256’s *verge* is a good one too. I +1’d you both.

Comment: @BraddSzonye I up voted his, too.

Comment: @BraddSzonye in my understanding a berm is "A raised bank or path ..." where the road built on an embankment.

Comment: Hmm. That was magnificently unclear! I understand a berm to be a raised bank (of earth/soil). It would apply to a road if a road was built on top.

Comment: A **berm** is utterly different and has no connection, whatsoever, to this in any way.  (It could be that some people use "berm" to mean shoulder, but then some people use potato to mean teacup.)

Comment: One random comment - read the fascinating book "Measuring America" for information on the widths of right-of-ways, the historical origin thereof, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The berm.

Ref.: Merriam-Webster Online

> ***berm***
>
> ***2** : the shoulder of a road*

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/berm

Comment: Sure, that might be a rare technical term for it, but then why not just use 'shoulder' (if that's right).

Comment: berm isn't that uncommon.

Comment: I learned the term *shoulder* as a child.  Then when I moved to Ohio, they were always called *berms*.  So we should not say *berm* is "rare" but only that it is "regional".

Comment: People do say berm in the US. I doubt it is regional.