# What do you call those high areas that give you a full view of the city?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, terminology

A place where you could sit and see something like this (with a fall if you step further):

[image: Sorry, since I don]

(Not looking for a technical term, just a common one).

Comment: _View property_.

Comment: janoChen, do you remember my comment under your question at this link? http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160110/what-do-you-call-the-empty-arid-zones-on-both-sides-of-a-highway#comment334195_160110

Comment: @Tristan r Oh, sorry. I  was never a good student. I'll try to remember from now on.

Comment: janoChen, that's a good effort from you.

Comment: '80s movie staple: "The Point". Things happen there

Comment: How about "hills".

Comment: @kolossus - Do you mean, as in Inspiration Point, good place for snogging/making-out?

Comment: Also could be a vista (for view)

Comment: Didn't see these in the answers: plateau or mount

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A common term for a place that affords such a view  would be a  [*scenic overlook*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scenic_overlook) or simply a *scenic view*:

> A **scenic overlook**, or just an **overlook, observation point, lookout, viewing point** or **vista point** is a high place where people can gather to view scenery (often with binoculars), and to photograph it. Scenic overlooks are typically created alongside mountain roads, often as a simple turnouts where motorists can pull over onto pavement, gravel, or grass on the right-of-way. Many are larger, having parking areas, while some (typically on larger highways) are off the road completely.

Here are some signs to such:

[image: scenic overlook]

[image: scenic view]

[image: I-80 view]

An older word, now more restricted to a [piece of architecture meant for such purposes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belvedere_(structure)), is a *belvidere* or *belvedere*.

[image: belvidere]

Comment: Hey that is a picture of the Hotel Monte **Vista**.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd Yup, good name for it, eh? :)

Comment: In AE it is overlook or vista.  Vista would be more used for beautiful scenery and overlook for utilitarian views.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd: Which dialect is "AE"? If "American English", then -- I disagree. I've always understood "vista" to be the beautiful view itself, not the place from which to view it.

Comment: @tchrist does it work if it isn't a tourist or public area?

Comment: @janoChen Sure, it’s still an overlook or a lookout.

Comment: "Overlook" isn't used to mean this in BrE.  (To British people, it's just a verb meaning to forget to consider something.)

Comment: Another possibility to add is 'vantage point'.

Answer (score 11):

It is called a **viewpoint**. (single word for viewing point)

Sometimes called **vantage point** as well.

> [viewpoint](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/viewpoint): a place from which something can be viewed

---

All the synonyms are mentioned in this article also:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlook

"Overlook" and "scenic overlook" is usually used for natural and mountain views. But to be more specific, you can always say "**city overlook**" or "**city viewpoint**".

---

Additions from Andrew Leach:

There is even a viewpoint sign:

[image]

<sub>Source: http://www.followthebrownsigns.com/viewpoint/</sub>

Viewpoint road sign:

[image]

<sub>Source: http://latterdaymusings.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/road-trip-oregon-jewel-mist-fishawk.html</sub>

---

It is also called a **scenic viewpoint**. It is used in USA too. When you say scenic view, it is the view that you are going to see but the viewpoint is the point where you see that view from.

[image]
<sub>Source: http://portlandwomensforum.com/photos.html</sub>

[image]
<sub>Source: http://www.milespointsandmaitais.com/category/uncategorized/</sub>

Comment: Those don’t sound quite right.  People would think a *viewpoint* would be one’s point of view.  The OED does not have an entry for *viewpoint*, and crowd-sourced references like Urban Dictionary are barely worth referencing.

Comment: @tchrist: No, in the UK there are roadsigns to Viewpoints. There's even a [symbol](http://www.followthebrownsigns.com/viewpoint/) for them. And OED **does** have entry, and a 150-year-old citation: "1858   W. Arnot *Laws from Heaven 2nd Ser.* xxv. 200   Change the view-point, and the scene will change."

Comment: @AndrewLeach Our signs are for [*Scenic View* or for *Scenic Overlook*](http://www.google.com/images?client=opera&rls=en&q=scenic+view+sign&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest&hl=en&sa=X&oi=image_result_group&ei=oStAU7zKHMKVygH13IH4DQ&ved=0CCMQsAQ).  And we actually use English not hieroglyphics. :)

Comment: @tchrist: You're right about *viewpoint* (which is why I'm not upvoting this answer) - but [*"vantage point over the city"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22vantage+point+over+the+city%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example, occurs 156 times in Google Books. In the UK, a specific place on a hillside that affords a good view is sometimes called a ***viewing point***. Sometimes you'll even see signs on pathways up the hill saying **Viewing point -->** to help you find them.

Comment: [Viewpoint on Highway 26](http://latterdaymusings.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/road-trip-oregon-jewel-mist-fishawk.html)

Comment: [Viewpoint on OSGB maps](http://www.sysmaps.co.uk/images/os_25k_key.jpg)

Comment: @AndrewLeach You might check my references, if you’d like.

Comment: Thanks for adding my entries and references to yours. Makes it seem like you thought of them, not me.

Comment: Well, I had them first. This makes it seem like you pinched them, which really isn’t cricket where I come from.

Comment: [Overlook](http://www.yelp.com/biz_photos/universal-city-overlook-los-angeles?select=ahPMG49hL0WHGVjwWi-JyA#ahPMG49hL0WHGVjwWi-JyA) describes the photo the OP posted. Oh, and I upvoted tchrist's answer as well.

Answer (score 7):

A Lookout.

"On that hill over there there is a lookout overseeing the whole city."

"Mary said she would come with me to point lookout this saturday."

Answer (score 5):

A common AE term for this type of view would be **vista**.  You would also see this name attached to hotels with great views.

> a large and beautiful view of an area of land or water

[image]

Comment: Isn't that what you actually _see_ rather than the place you see it _from_? That's how I would use it anyway and your definition seems to agree.

Comment: @terdon - It is for both.  That is why you see so many hotels that have great views use it in their name.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, the Hotel Great Vista, _has_  a vista, it isn't one though.

Comment: @terdon - it is both.  Google vista and go to images, get past the microsoft stuff and you get points with great views.

Comment: The place is called a "vista point".

Comment: @ermanen - It can be referred to as just vista.  Maybe that is shortened for vista point, whatever.  It is referred to as just vista from where I am from in the US.

Comment: Just helping with your answer.

Comment: Wow, 313.9 million people in the US all call it a *vista*. I'd call it a hill, where I live I'm surrounded by them, and there are numerous hotels and B&Bs which are called *Bella Vista* or even *Bellavista* which have breathtaking views and panoramas. :))

Comment: In your picture the place to see the Vista is called a Vista Point, cognate with the spanish Punto de Vista, and the correct english phrase Viewpoint for such a location.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, there are many Bella Vistas. It means "Beautiful View" and refers to the thing you can see, not the place you can see it from.

Comment: I know what bella vista means @DavidRicherby, a view/scenic/vistapoint in Italian is [*punto panoramico*](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&espv=210&es_sm=122&biw=1366&bih=653&q=punto+panoramico+italia&oq=punto+panoramico+italia&gs_l=serp.3...10250.13395.0.14517.7.7.0.0.0.0.290.1223.0j5j2.7.0....0...1c.1.39.serp..5.2.270.dtmgYwIY7rA)

Answer (score 3):

You could say : "a room/balcony with a view..."

Comment: If the place in question was a room or balcony. The photo in the question appears to have been taken from a hill.

Answer (score 3):

Not an extremely common word, but a nice one: **[promontory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promontory_fort)**.

Answer (score 3):

### acropolis

Since you mentioned "with a fall if you step further", I offer something "with precipitous sides":

> An **acropolis** (from *akros* or *akron*, "highest", "topmost", "outermost" and *polis*, "city"; plural in English: acropoles, acropoleis or acropolises) is a settlement, especially a citadel, built upon an area of elevated ground—frequently a hill with precipitous sides, chosen for purposes of defense.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acropolis)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider "high point."

E.g.

> [When we were almost at camp, we arrived at a high point looking out onto an incredible Incan city.](http://chrissouthamerica.blogspot.fr/2008/01/lake-titicaca-and-machu-picchu.html)

Comment: 0kay. The expression "high point" should fit better then.

Answer (score 2):

In Australia we would call it a **Lookout**.

Comment: already proposed

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for a "common" expression, another is "bird's eye view."